# undefined reference to std::thread::detach() and others

Tags: mingw-w64, stdthread

I am compiling c++-14 code using std::thread class with mingw w64 (gcc 9.3) and the posix threading model (not win32). The linker links with `-lpthread -lwinpthread` but I nevertheless get:

```
undefined reference to `std::thread::_State::~_State()'
undefined reference to `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())'
undefined reference to `std::thread::detach()'
```

The host is Ubuntu 20.04 and the MinGW version is the default packaged version (7.0.0); I also tested with backported 8.0.0 (gcc . There does not seem to be a more recent packaged toolchain available, so I did not try an upgrade of mingw (the latest is 9.0.0).

Any hints?

***EDIT:*** I switched to https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads header-only implementation of std::thread and win32 thread model. CLosing the question.

Comment: Could you show the full linker command?

Comment: In the end I switched to the `win32` thread model and used this header-only implementation of std::thread without any further issue https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads .